# On $\gamma$-graded pieces of the localization sequence for G-theory (i.e. for K'-theory)

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

There is a well-known Quillen's localization sequence for (algebraic) K-theory: $\dots\to K_p^Y(X)\to K_p(X)\to K_p(X-Y)\to \dots$, where $Y\to X$ is a closed embedding of schemes. 
Now suppose that $X$ is regular (and excellent of finite dimension, if needed).
Another well-known fact is that (in this case) the relative K-theory group 
$K_p^Y(X)$ is isomorphic to $K'_p(Y)$ (some authors denote this by $G_p(Y)$; note that $Y$ is not necessarily regular!).

Now, I tensor this long exact sequence by $\mathbb{Q}$. Can I consider the $i$-th graded piece of the $\gamma$-filtration for this long exact sequence? Certainly, $K^{}(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$  and $K^*(X-Y)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ are endowed with $\gamma$-filtration, but I am not quite sure about $K'_p(Y)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ (one of my problems here is that I am interested in quite a general situation). Also, could I say that the $i$-th level of the $\gamma$-filtration for $K'_p(Y)$ is some (which one??) level of its niveau filtration?

Which references are most appropriate for these matters? I believe that for rational coefficients these things are easier than for integral ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic reference is Soule's paper "Operations en K-theorie algebrique" (Can. J. Math. 37 (1985) 488-550). Essentially, there is a grading on $K'$-theory (with rational coefficients) enabling one to interpret the localisation sequence as the long exact sequence of motivic homology. The filtration comes from the $\gamma$-filtration on $K_*^Y(X)$, the $K$-theory with support.

Tamme's article in the Beilinson conjectures book (http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/math/u/schneider/publ/beilinson-volume/index.html) is a good survey of this, but he sticks to the case of schemes over a field.

I am not sure I understand your final question, since even for $K$-theory of nice schemes (e.g. spectra of fields) the $\gamma$- and niveau filtrations don't agree except for $K_0$.

Comment: Even when tensored by $\mathbb{Q}$? Thank you!

Comment: Also, could you give a reference for the $K_0$-case?

Comment: SGA6 is the bible for this (the introductory Expose 0 by Grothendieck summarises what's inside nicely)

Comment: Another good reference for the gamma and dimension filtration is Gillet's article for the K-theory handbook, available at http://www.math.uic.edu/~henri/preprints/K-Theory_Chow_Groups-6.pdf. It contains two different proofs for smooth schemes over a field. 

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the $i$-th level of the filtration for $K^*(X)$ (and so also for $K^Y(X)$) by definition becomes the $d-i$-th level of the filtration for $K'(Y)$, where $d$ is the dimension of $X$? Is this convention (for the levels of the filtrations) canonical?

Comment: If $X$ is smooth over a field this is correct, but there are numerological difficulties if the base scheme is, say, the spectrum of a DVR (not surprisingly).

Comment: For X smooth over a field, see   
Gillet & Soulé, "Filtrations on higher algebraic K-theory" AMS
Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. vol 67 (MR1743238) for the result on higher K-theory